# Efficiently add in-order data to TreeMap?

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have a basic tree/algorithm question for Java:

Say I am constructing a new TreeMap:

```
TreeMap<KeyType,ValType> myTreeMap = new TreeMap<>();
```

And I also have an existing array of data that is already in Comparison order:

```
KeyType myArray[] = new KeyType[]{.......};
```

Is there a way to populate the TreeMap with this data in O(n) time? I.e., is this the most efficient method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    myTreeMap.put(myArray[i],"blah");
}
```

Or is there a way to take advantage of the fact that the data is already in order to avoid a possible O(lg n) insertions/tree-balancing?

Comment: Ah, yes it is. Thanks! That'll teach me to search better first.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279840/how-to-initialize-a-treemap-with-pre-sorted-data) is another solution. I have decided to simply use putAll() when copying from another TreeMap and a custom sorted structure when that is not available.