# Efficiently read pre-sorted data into SortedMap in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a file with data lines like

```
<Long> <...Other Stuff...>
```

which I want to read into a Java `SortedMap<Long, <OtherStuffType>>` (or something similar with a fast `get()` method for multiple lookups). Now, my data is already sorted, so does there exist an efficient implementation of `SortedSet` for this case - e.g. one with a guaranteed constant-time `put()` when a new entry has a larger key than any existing entry.

Comment: Are you expecting to ever add/remove entries to/from the Map after you initialize it from the data file?

Comment: If you just need to keep the order on pre-sorted data and do not need to add elements later, use the `LinkedHashMap` then, because your data is already sorted, it will remain sorted after you populate it.

Comment: If this is not a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279840/how-to-initialize-a-treemap-with-pre-sorted-data), please edit your question to define _efficient_ and  explain how the accepted answer is insufficient

Comment: @trashgod duplicate of which one? Under efficient the author means constant time insertions for constantly increasing key values (as the question clearly states)

Comment: @OlegSklyar: duplicate now cited; if "the author means constant time insertions" then the author should say so in context. If you disagree, please vote to reopen.

Comment: I'll accept that it's the same question - I asked for a constant time put() for increasing key values, but a linear time put for a pre-sorted putAll() would also be a valid solution. But that said, I don't think the only answer given is terribly useful, since it is based on an assumption about the internal implementation of the putAll() method. I'll continue the discussion on the other issue.